# Change LHSprite position from code (levelhelper-XCODE)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, position

I'm trying to move all sprites with the same tag some inches to the right.
I have tried 4 different type of expressions in order to do so, but nothing worked. Here is what i ve done so far...

```
-(void) moveSprites {

NSArray* spritesWithTag = [lh spritesWithTag: BOXES1]
for (LHSprite* spr in spritesWithTag)
(NSLog (@"name is %@", [spr uniqueName]);

CGPoint newposition = ccpSub (ccp(-50,0), [spr position]);
     //generating the new position for the elements

[spr transformPosition: newposition];
//first attemp, should work but for some reason it doesn't work

spr.position = newposition;
//2nd attemp
b2Vec2 newpositionVector (newposition.x, newposition.y);
[spr body]->SetTransform(newpositionVector, 0);
//third try
[spr setPosition:newposition];
//last form
}
```

When i run the app the method call works fine and all sprites with tag BOXES1 appear in the output tab, but its position hasn't changed at all. Any idea over why is it happening. What did I wrong? Is there any other way to move an sprite or are them prevented from moving in some other form i dont know?  Those are static sprites, dont know if this affects... thanks!